# Setting up a nginx RTMP server. I have everything working minus Facebook Live

Tags: linux, streaming, nginx, facebook, rtmp

Hi all  I am trying to set up a new RTMP server, using the directions found at https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/ and am running into an issue with Facebook Live. I have a feeling it comes down to their new only accepting SSL only connections

> Deprecation Support for RTMP server URLs is being deprecated, and
>   non-secure URLs will no longer supported as of May 1. Please verify
>   that your encoder supports RTMPS, and update your encoder settings to
>   insert your new secure server URL in order to continue.

so I am running into the issue where I try to stop and start nginx with this as the bottom of my config:

```
rtmp {  
        server {
                listen 1935;
                listen 443;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        push 'rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/insertedmykeyhere';

                }
        }
}
```

I am getting:

> root@localhost:/usr/local/nginx/conf# sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
>   -s stop nginx: [emerg] invalid port in url "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/218

and I can't do anything else with it.  When I comment out the facebook, I can stream to Twitch, Mixer, YouTube, etc. with no issue, but this is holding me back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you will have to stream with out rtmps.. I know I am in the same boat as well however my setup is a bit more complex since I use two rtmp servers at the moment.. I am wondering how many people this will affect... I did find this but not sure if it will solve my issues still digging around..

https://gist.github.com/mrbar42/09c149059f72da2f09e652d4c5079919

https://www.jakobstoeck.de/2017/how-to-encrypt-rtmp-or-anything-really-over-ssl-tls/

Again I am in the same boat but this is the path i am trying to work down at the moment..  Unless I find some thing different out there.. To be honest though facebook doesn't really have that much to offer anyway when it comes to quality streaming of games so.. In my scenario i will just quit streaming to facebook if i can't find the way to rtmp it..